# Inserting an empty row in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to introduce a graphical separation between group of rows in a DataGridView.

Which are the options I have:
 - Should I introduce an empty row?
 - Should I work with borders and/or the paint methods ?

Comment: You can add a new row and change its properties as much as you wish, but the number of columns on it will remain. To change that (to merge the columns in the separation row) you would have to rely on paint events.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This increases the lower border of the row at specified [Index]:

```
DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[Index];
row.DividerHeight = 1;
```

Note that [DividerHeigth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.dividerheight.aspx) uses the space of the row, so if you set it to 10 it can cover half row (for me, 1 is enough).

There is also [DividerWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.dividerwidth.aspx) property to separate groups of columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
grid.Rows.Insert(index, 1);
var addedRow = grid.Rows[index];
```

This inserts 1 empty templated row at 'index'.

Comment: my problem is that I don't want a templated row. I want kind of a separator row

Answer (score 0):

With the `Rows.Add()` method you add a new row, you can obtain a reference to it by using:

```
var newRow = dg.Rows[dg.Rows.Add()];
```

So you can manipulate your new row after, example:

```
newRow.Cells["myColumn"].Value = "asd";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataGridViewRow DGVR= (DataGridViewRow)yourDataGridView.Rows[0].Clone();
DGVR.Cells[0].Value = "XYZ";
DGVR.Cells[1].Value = 50.2;
yourDataGridView.Rows.Add(DGVR);
```